# Can you run wires to an inductive heating coil or will that be a bad idea and why?

Tags: wiring, heat, inductance, inductive

I have an inductive heating circuit that runs at around 5A at 24V (I'm estimating here).  Is it possible to place the inductive heating coil a distance away from the circuit and connect the circuit to the coil via very high-current copper wires, or will intermediate objects made of metal that are close to the wires also inductively heat up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be fine. The inductive heater works by inducing an eddy current into the metal object that is being heated.

It does so by creating an alternating magnetic field around the coil which by Faraday's law of induction creates small potentials inside the metal object creating the eddy currents. These small currents cause Joule heating of the object which is how the inductive heater warms objects.

The inductance of this coil is very large compared to that of a straight wire in order to produce the required magnetic field. The current flowing through your wires has negligible inductance and will not cause a large enough magnetic field to heat nearby objects.

Think of it like this. Do your TV wires cause near by metal objects to heat up when it draws current?

Comment: I guess to make sure I can run the wires on two different paths, then they'll converge near the coil.  This is good news!  Thanks.

Comment: @enjoys Rather run them close together, even twisted together. Wires run further apart generate larger magnetic fields. The large loop forms an inductor and will try to heat the walls of your box, nearby objects etc. Keep the (unwanted) loop area as small as possible.